# So I am trying to make a quick app the calculates the multiplier of certain teams when players are betting on them

Tags: ios, swift

For example say we have two teams: Team a and team b with starting values of 1 so, also say we have 4 players. The main idea is that the more players that bet on team a, will make the the value of team b go up and the value of team a will go down so that if you bet 20 dollars on team a and 3 other people are betting on it then the value will be 25 cents per dollar won. I'll apply a greater definition if someone doesn't understand, but let me get to the actual part of the question that I need answered.

Basically I have started by creating the teams I have given them arbitrary names so that no one knows what I am doing with this. But basically I have created a enum with 3 teams and inside this enum I have created a function that will multiply the values, and I did it just like one of the swift video says how to do, but I am getting an error when I name two values, naming just one is ok, but the minute that I name two I get an "tuple pattern element label 'num' must be '_'. I don't know what this means and I have tried to search for this and found nothing. I am using swift three I don't know if that makes a difference considering the videos are updated to this version of the language.

Here is the code that is giving me problems:

```
  enum Teams {
      case blahOne(Float,Float)
      case blahTwo(Float, Float)
      case blahThree(Float, Float)    

      func calcMultiplier() -> Multi {

          switch self {

          case .blahOne(num: let num, multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
          case .blahTwo(num: let num,multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
          case .blahThree(num: let num,multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, multi: multi)
          }
      }    
  }

  struct Multi {
      var num: Float
      var multi: Float    
  }
```

it is giving me problems in the function where I say "num: let num, multi: let multi"

this is the error in case you didn't feel like reading and skipped to the bottom.

" tuple pattern element label 'num' must be '_' "

Comment: Very strange code, making it hard to figure out what exactly is the issue. Why the back-to-back-to-back lets? (In fact two of them per call.) Why the *12* times you have "num" in three lines of code - one with let, one in naming on the return, one the variable being returned - ??? I'm guessing if you split that up - "let num1"... "return num: num2" would either totally break your code (which it probably will if what you are trying is recursive calls) or illuminate the exact issue.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue but I'll tryi it real quick.... did it and it changed nothing still the same error @dfd

Comment: and this is exactly how treehouse has taught in their videos, besides some things like adding an init method to Multi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having problems because your enum's associated values don't have labels.  If you give them labels, your code would work:

```
enum Teams {
    case blahOne(num: Float, multi: Float)
    case blahTwo(num: Float, multi: Float)
    case blahThree(num: Float, multi: Float)

    func calcMultiplier() -> Multi {

        switch self {

        case .blahOne(num: let num, multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        case .blahTwo(num: let num,multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        case .blahThree(num: let num,multi: let multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        }
    }
}

struct Multi {
    var num: Float
    var times: Float
}
```

---

If you don't need the labels on the associated values, you can just eliminate them from the cases.  Also note that `case .blahOne(let num, let multi):` can be written more succinctly as `case let .blahOne(num, multi):`.

```
enum Teams {
    case blahOne(Float, Float)
    case blahTwo(Float, Float)
    case blahThree(Float, Float)

    func calcMultiplier() -> Multi {

        switch self {

        case let .blahOne(num, multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        case let .blahTwo(num, multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        case let .blahThree(num, multi): return Multi(num: num, times: multi)
        }
    }
}

struct Multi {
    var num: Float
    var times: Float
}
```

Comment: Note, I changed your `Multi` struct to have a `times` property.  It wasn't clear whether you wanted it to be `multi` or `times` since you were creating it both ways.

Comment: The bottom solution worked I didn't try the others, and yeah it was like that because I had changed a bunch of stuff randomly to see if I could fix the error thanks for the help @vacawama